# responsive "overflow-x: hidden !important;" not working

Tags: html, css

On a full size monitor there is no issue, but when I try responsive screen sizes in the dev tools (larger or smaller sizes), an x-overflow scroll is generated. I have tried `body { overflow-x: hidden !important }`, but there is still an x-axis scroll. there is a nav bar that is hidden to the right of the page unless the menu is clicked. when the menu has been clicked and the nav bar is showing, there is no overflow. When I remove the code for my navbar, there is also no overflow. The issues surely lies in the navbar. Is there an alternative method or solution to ensure the page does not have an overflow-x scroll, or can someone point out what needs to be changed in my nav code to enable `overflow-x: hidden` to work?

```css
#hamburger__menu__home {
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu__btn__home {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 12;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: fixed;
}
.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger,
.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::before,
.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}
.menu__btn__home .menu__hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box__home {
  right: 0 !important;
}
.menu__box__home {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(79, 112, 148, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition-duration: .5s;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger__menu__home">
  <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu__btn__home" for="menu__toggle">
    <div id="menu" class="home__menu">MENU</div>
    <div><span class="menu__hamburger"></span></div>
  </label>

  <ul class="menu__box__home">
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="about.html">ABOUT IMPACT</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="facilities.html">FACILITIES</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="people.html">PEOPLE</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="publications.html">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="epo.html">EDUCATION / PUBLIC OUTREACH</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="sservi.html">SSERVI / TEAMS</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="media.html">MEDIA</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="meetings.html">MEETINGS</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try adding html `{ overflow: hidden; }` to your code. This can prevent the entire page from having an x-axis scrollbar. However, this method might affect other elements on your page, so use it carefully.

Comment: An alternative approach to consider might be using `transform: translateX` for handling your navigation bar's visibility, instead of using `position: absolute;` with `right`. The transform property does not affect the overall document flow and is less likely to cause overflow issues.